# Display 2 divs next to each other and together bigger then the screen

Tags: css

I've been searching for hours but I can't find a way to place 2 div's next to each other.
The below example works fine when the div's are smaller then the screen but when they are bigger then the screen they are below each other.
Also I would like the same classes for 2 pages:

- 1 page they both fit on the screen and I'd like to display them next to each other (not one on the left and one on the right)
- the other page together they are bigger then the screen. (Sideways scrolling is no problem)

Take this example:

```
<style>
.wrapper
{
    border:1px solid Red;
    display: inline-block;
}

.left 
{
    float:left;
    color: Green;
    border:1px solid Green;
}

.right 
{
    float:right;
    color: Blue;
    border:1px solid Blue;
}
</style>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left">
        ASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDF
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        ASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDF
    </div>
    <div class="clear" />
</div>
```

In the actual design ASDF is replaced by a big `<table>`.
As I said above I've been searching for hours but can find a solution so I'm sorry if this has been asked before.

Comment: Thanks, and it's certainly reassuring to note that my answer is supported by [Jon's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10244647/82548) (better-explained) answer =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. The wrapper div isn't necessary for the two to be lined up, but if you have it for other reasons (like a border, background, etc.), then it does not need to be set to `inline-block`.
2. Nothing technically needs to float. `inline-block` has the same effect and is more appropriate. Having said that, one float is needed to make things as fluid as possible and will be mentioned in a second.
3. Something that makes this and other css magic involving inline-block tricky and error-prone is that the element is treated in some ways like an inline element and in other ways like a block. This is not cross-browser consistent. Generally, this means that it can have block-level styling (like border, and width), and inline-level styling. Generally people just think of it as blocks that fall horizontally, "in a line". But inline element properties from a wrapper div such as font-size and white-space come in to effect as well (which is just annoying).

Having said all of that, here is the bare-bones recipe for side-by-side block elements that exceed the browser window and are inside of a block-level wrapper:

1. The inner blocks need to be set to `inline-block`.
2. The outer wrapper needs to have `white-space` set to `nowrap`, just as if you wanted a long line of text to expand horizontally beyond the browser window.
3. The outer wrapper needs to be set to `float: left; clear: both;`, because otherwise the wrapper's width will not go past the window width. The alternative is to set the width of the wrapper, but if you don't know how far it will expand, the float will force the wrapper to automatically shrink or grow to the width of it's contents. The `clear:both` prevents the floating from affecting any surrounding elements.

So for the following HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left">ASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDF</div>
    <div class="right">ASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDF</div>
</div>​
```

You would need the following CSS as a bare minimum:

```
.wrapper {
         white-space: nowrap;
         float:left;
         clear: both;
}

.left, .right{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

And then, for your example, you would add:

```
.wrapper {
         border: 1px solid red;
}

.left 
{
    color: Green;
    border:1px solid Green;

}

.right 
{
    color: Blue;
    border:1px solid Blue;
}​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/crazytonyi/jTknm/

Answer (score 2):

This is one approach that could be used, coupling `white-space: nowrap` in the parent `.wrapper` element with `display: inline-block` in the child `.left` and `.right` elements:

```
.wrapper
{
    /* other stuff */
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.left 
{
    display: inline-block;
    /* other stuff */
}

.right 
{
    display: inline-block;
    /* other stuff */
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/CEhqp/1/).

Comment: In your demo, you are using `inline-block` on the wrapper to make the width stretch to inner-divs. The only problem with that the following block element will be treated as part of that inline block. Using float and clear:both will stretch it and keep it from breaking surrounding flow.

Comment: Good point; I hadn't realised that I'd left that in place. Edited-out, and [updated the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/CEhqp/1/). Thanks =)

Comment: Now you have the other problem I banged against: the wrapper border is the width of the window instead of the inner divs.  Floating the wrapper was the only solution I found without hard-setting the wrapper width.

Answer (score 0):

Erm, you need to use `float:left` for both them to begin with. Then force `overflow:show` for the wrapper or perhaps use the newer CSS 3 property `overflow-x:scroll`. Let me know if it still doesn't work.

Okay I have tested for you. The reason why this is not working is because you haven't specified fixed widths and some other stuff. Here is the working code:

```
<style>
.wrapper
{
    border:1px solid Red;
    width:100%;
    overflow-x:scroll;
}

.left 
{
    float:left;
    width:500px;
    color: Green;
    border:1px solid Green;
}

.right 
{
    float:left;
    width:500px;
    color: Blue;
    border:1px solid Blue;
}
</style>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left">
        ASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDF
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        ASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDF
    </div>
    <div class="clear" />
</div>
```

Then if you want to specify widths, either use Javascript to determine them on page load or use CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without floating by setting the inner divs to `display: inline-block` and letting the outer div have `white-space: nowrap`:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left">left</div><div class="right">right</div>
</div>

.wrapper { border: 1px red solid; white-space: nowrap }
.wrapper div { display: inline-block; width: 70% } /* 2*70% = 140% of .wrapper */
```

[**See it in action**](http://jsfiddle.net/zYCEW/).

Be careful to not leave any whitespace between closing the first and opening the second div, because that will manifest as visible space in the render.

Comment: The only catch is that the border of the wrapper ends before the inner div content.  Using a float on the wrapper extends it across the inner content.

Answer (score 0):

Your divs need widths, try:

```
<div id="left"><p>Some content here...</p></div>
<div id="right"><p>Some content here...</p></div>

<style>
    #left, #right { float:left; color: Green; border:1px solid Green; width:49%; }
    #left { margin-right:1%; }
</style>
```

Comment: They don't! It took me forever to get it to work without widths, but it can be done.  See http://jsfiddle.net/crazytonyi/jTknm/

Comment: The problem is I want to use a width because this is class is generic across pages and I just want it to use the space it needs. Thanks for your suggestion though!